# What should a zebra finch's nest be like?

Tags: birds, zebra-finch

I got a zebra finch pair and they had a plastic nest in the cage which they used to lay eggs but none ever hatched.

Since the plastic nest was utterly ugly and not giving any results, I made one more natural from a wood that I drilled and hollowed inside pretty similar in size to the plastic one.

But the birds don't use it as a nest after several days, and I'm puzzled about the reason. Is there any checklist or trick I can try?

Comment: Do they have this nest only, or do they have a second one for hiding and sleeping? What kind of material do you provide them, to built their own nest inside the wooden nest? I have no own experience, but I read about different materials and also two "houses" if one wants to breed them.